# Convex Hull reading XY co-ords in Python

Tags: python, convex-hull, convex-polygon

I need to come up with a convex hull algorithm to read through a bunch of X , Y co-ordinates and outline the image..
i'm coding in python
Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. What should the output be?

Comment: Perhaps take a look here: http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~compgeom/pycgalvisual/whypython.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Are there any more details or constraints to your question? After searching wikipedia for "Convex hull algorithms", it gave me a list of algorithms, of which I clicked "Monotone Chain"
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain

Comment: oh i'm sorry.. the output needs to be the outline of the image that i've set for the program to read.
As of right now i have figured out a way to read the XY values of the image.. now i need to implement a convex hull algorithm that reads the XY values and gives me the outline of the image..
Any ideas?
I've looked at quite a few algorithms out there but i'm not sure how best to go about implementing this..

Comment: Most out there are generating random points and then outlining the image..